# Prove $f(x) < 0 \forall x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable and:

- $f''(x)\leq f(x)$    $\forall x$
- $f(0)=0$
- $f'(0)=0$

How can I prove $f(x)\leq 0 $    $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^+$? (it intuitively seems obvious) I just have basic knowledge of analysis so please keep it simple, thanks!

Comment: you state that $f(0)=0$ but then again say that the domain is $\mathbb{R}^+$ in other words $x\in(0;\infty)$, thus $f(0)$ shouldnt be defined since $0$ is not in the domain. Or does $\mathbb{R}^+$ mean $x\in[0;\infty)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us work on the interval $[0,1]$. Now assume that there is $a \in (0,1)$ such that 
$f(a) >0$
 then by mean value there is

$$f(a)=f^{\prime}(b)a$$
 and 
$$f^{\prime}(b)=f^{\prime\prime}(c)b$$
with $c<b<a$
This implies that

$$f(a) \leq f(c)ab$$

and this gives that 
$$\frac{f(a)}{a^2}\leq\frac{f(a)}{ab}\leq  f(c)$$

Thus we can define a sequence $a_n$ decreasing so that

$$\frac{f(a)}{a^{2n}}\leq f(a_n)$$ and since $a<1$ this is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

You have $f^{\prime\prime}(x)\leq f(x)$. Hence $f^{\prime\prime}(x)+f^{\prime}(x)\leq f(x)+f^{\prime}(x)$. Multiplying by $\exp(x)$, you get $(\exp(x) f^{\prime}(x))^{\prime}\leq (\exp(x) f(x))^{\prime}$
and so the function $\exp(x)(f(x)-f^{\prime}(x))$ is increasing. Now show  that $f(x)-f^{\prime}(x)\geq 0$ and use a similar trick to finish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, $f''(x) \le f(x) \implies f''(x)-f'(x) \le f(x) - f'(x) $ .

Define a function,  $$ G(x) = f(x)-f'(x) $$
Note that, $G(x)$ is also differentiable function.  So we have, 
$$ -G'(x) \le G(x) \implies e^x(G(x)+G'(x)) \ge 0 \implies (G(x)e^x)' \ge 0 $$

And, so using monotonic behavior of $ G(x)e^x$, we have $$G(x)e^x \ge G(0)e^0 = 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R^{+}} $$

This gives $ f(x)-f'(x) \ge 0 $.

Again using the same idea, we have , $$ e^{-x}f(x) - e^{-x}f'(x) \ge 0 \implies (e^{-x}f(x))' \le 0 $$

And so, $$e^{-x}f(x) \le e^{0}f(0) = 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$$

So we have $f(x) \le 0$ and we are done! $\Box$